# mmap: python int too large to convert to c long

Tags: python, mmap, beagleboneblack

The context of my problem is that I'm using the Beaglebone Black's PRU to write something to the memory and read it with python running on the ARM. I'm following [a guide](http://hipstercircuits.com/beaglebone-pru-ddr-memory-access-the-right-way/) on how to access memory.

When I run the Python code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “ddr_write.py”, line 30, in
    ddr_mem = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), ddr_filelen, offset=ddr_offset) # mmap the right area
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

`ddr_filelen` is `0x10040000` and `ddr_offset` is `0x89980000`

My Python version 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

You are prbably using a 32 bit platform which has the max as 2,147,483,647 decimal which is 0x7fffffff as compared to the value ddr_offset = 0x89980000 which is 2,308,440,064 in decimal. This would give you the error that you are seeing.

Comment: Is there a way for me to work around this short of reinstalling things?

Comment: @DavidQ You would have to set up so that the C library can handle larger values. You would need to see if your library can handle 'long long' or if it is really a 64 bit platform, in which case you would have to set up your basic C library to know that fact. Since I do not know what system you are running and do not have access, at present to compilers, I cannot answer you question further than I have done. Sorry about that.